# Plotting a conditional expression

Tags: plotting, conditional

I'm trying to plot the feasible region of a maximization problem with `PlotRegion3D`. This region is the intersection of two constraints and I'd like to plot also the line that goes through the points in which both constraints are satisfied as equalities. My end goal is to have this feasible region embedded in a `Manipulate` environment and, therefore, my current approach of computing the line manually is not adequate.

My code is

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
X = {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {4, 4}};
qVec = Array[q, 3];
kVec = {10, 15};
a = 1/2;
needs = Transpose[X].qVec^(1/a);
max = Table[(Min[kVec[[1]]/X[[i, 1]],kVec[[2]]/X[[i, 2]]])^a,{i, 1, 3}];
r1 = RegionPlot3D[needs[[1]] <= kVec[[1]] && needs[[2]] <= kVec[[2]], {q[1], 0, 
max[[1]]}, {q[2], 0, max[[2]]}, {q[3], 0, max[[3]]}, Mesh -> None];
inter = ParametricPlot3D[{(2 z^2 - 5/2)^a, (25/4 - 3 z^2)^a,z}, {z, Sqrt[5/4], Sqrt[25/12]}];
Show[{r1, inter}]
```

Ideally, I'd use the output of `Solve[Flatten[{needs == kVec, Thread[qVec >= 0]}], qVec, Reals]` in the `ParametricPlot3D`.

Also, feel free to suggest improvements in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
inter = ParametricPlot3D[
   qVec /.
     Solve[Flatten[{needs == kVec, Thread[qVec >= 0]}], Rest@qVec, 
      Reals] // Evaluate,
   {q[1], 0, max[[1]]}
   ];
Show[{r1, inter}]
```

[image]

This simply solves for `q[2]` and `q[3]` as a function of `q[1]` (notice the `Rest` in the argument to `Solve`), and uses the result to parametrize `qVec` with `q[1]`, which is then plotted.